# how to access kubernetes service from outside the VM

Tags: kubernetes

I have a VM installed on my desktop which is running windows 8 and with minikube i
am running a single-node kubernetes cluster on the VM. Now i want to expose a service so as to access it from outside my VM e.g from chrome browser of my desktop or from anywhere else.

I have already tried the "kubectl expose" command but didn't succeed. So what should i do to implement this?

Comment: Are you using [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) or how have you set up the cluster?

Comment: yes i am using minikube to set up the cluster

Comment: ok, then all your services will be exposed on the `minikube ip`. You can also use `minikube service <name>` to get to them.

Comment: The above command ( minikube service <name-of-service> ) is returning this error " E1130 12:14:10.330498   26042 cluster.go:630] Error getting machine status: Error getting host state: machine does not exist ".

Comment: Do you have the VM network interface on bridge mode so it get an IP of your LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the nodeport service when you made the kubernetes service? If so, you can access your service through your vm it's ip and the port you assigned with the nodeport k8s service.